# How to create redirect URL that detect as referral on google analytics?

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, google-analytics, referrals

I have 2 websites web1.com and web2.com. I have tried to redirect web1.com/a to web2.com, but Google Analytics did not detect the redirection as a referral from web1.com. I am using Wordpress with redirection plugin. Is there a way to make it detect as referral from web1.com?

Answer (score 0):

It wont, it will only be a referral is there is a follow-through link. You need to paste your Google Analytics the code into the header of your redirecting page (if possible) as well as the landing page. That is really the only way you can track redirects. Otherwise you will need to redirect through  your HTACCESS file and paste the following code into your redirecting file.

```
web1.com >> web2.com/?utm_medium=301&utm_source=web2.com
```

Comment: Strictly speaking that will not track the redirect as referrer - you'd need to set utm_medium to "referrer" if you wanted to go the data into the referral report.